# How to override the existing content inside the HTML element by jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I want to override the existing content inside the HTML element. I tried with method append() to the element but then it only append content to the existing, I was wonder is there anyway to override the whole content in the element ?

Comment: use `.html()` to change, `.append()` will just add

Comment: Add answer down below! Here is your [source](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-htmlString).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```js
$('input.append').click(function() {
  $('span').append('append')



})
$('input.html').click(function() {
  $('span').html('html')



})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>span value</span>
<input type='button' class='append' value='Append' />
<input type='button' class='html' value='Html' />
```

1. use .html() to change.
2. append() will just add.

Comment: Glad to help mate :)

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
.empty().html("New Content");
```

This will empty your element's content and you may add whatever you wish then.

Answer (score 0):

**first empty that element and then add html**

```
eg: $('div').empty()

$('div').html('<h1>some text</h1>')
```